# Trouble importing tensorflow-gpu in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, cudnn

I have installed `tensorflow-gpu` in `Ubuntu 18.04` with `CUDA 9.0` and `CuDnn 7.4`. Although it got successfully installed but when I import it

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

I get error msg

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Detailed [error log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/upi4dyhssg3v3d3/error_log.txt?dl=0)

Earlier I have installed and used it without any problem but as soon as I have reinstalled Ubuntu I'm getting this error.

From error is seems tensorflow is looking for `CUDA 10.0`, Do I need to install a lower version of `tensorfow-gpu` current version is `tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) seem to suggest that you need CUDA 10 for tensorflow 1.13. Downgrading to tensorflow 1.12 (or upgrading CUDA) should solve the issue.